# Selecting an integer from an Access Database using SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

Trying to select an integer from an Access Database using an SQL statement in VB

```
Dim cmdAutoTypes As New OleDbCommand
Dim AutoTypesReader As OleDbDataReader

cmdAutoTypes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AutoTypes WHERE TypeId = '" & cboTypeIds.Text & "'"

AutoTypesReader = cmdAutoTypes.ExecuteReader
```

Error message says: "OleDbException was unhandled: Data type mismatch in criteria expression." and points to the AutoTypesReader = cmdAutoTypes.ExecuteReader line

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the value of `cboTypeIds.Text`, and the resulting `CommandText` that is getting sent to the database.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. String concatenation like that for sql data is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Rather make use of [OleDbParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

This will also avoid [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes in the query string.  You're searching for a number, not a string.

```
cmdAutoTypes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AutoTypes WHERE TypeId = " & cboTypeIds.Text
```

Comment: Well, now it gives an error: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TypeId ='."

Comment: Are you sure that cboTypeIds.Text is a valid integer?

Answer (score 0):

Hi In access SQL you can't use single quote around your Integer type.

so 
command text will be.. "SELECT * FROM AutoTypes WHERE TypeId = " & cboTypeIds.Text & " and .... "

Answer (score 0):

In Access SQL, don't quote numeric constants.

And test whether `IsNull(cboTypeIds)`.  You can't do what you were planning to do until a value has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use string concatenation when you build your SQL query, use parameters instead.

```
Dim cmd As OledbCommand = Nothing
Dim reader as OleDbDataReader = Nothing
Try
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM AutoTypes WHERE TypeId = @Id"
    cmd = New OledbCommand(query, connection)
    //adding parameter implicitly
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", cboTypeIds.Text)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Catch ex As Exception
    Messagebox.Show(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
```

You can also explicitly state the parameter data type.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = cboTypeIds.Text
```

Hope this helps.